# Unable to introducing generics into Typescript method without losing object key typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm creating a method in Typescript that extracts allowable property types from an object of a constrained generic type.

Essentially, I have a type `ParticipantBase` which has properties `first: string, last: string, extras: [key: string]: string`. I have made a function `getAllowedEntry` which takes an object of type ParticipantBase and a key at which the value in the `ParticipantBase` object is of type `AllowableType`. This works just fine.

I want to be able to add generics to this function, but as soon as I do, errors begin popping up and the Typescript compiler no longer seems to be able to guarantee the typings.

I think there's something fundamental here that I'm not understanding about typings and generics in Typescript, if someone could help me out, that would be great.

Minimal Sample (also available in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)):

```js
type PropertiesOfType<U, V> = {
  [P in keyof U]: U[P] extends V ? P : never;
}[keyof U];

type AllowedPropertyTypes = string | number;

type ParticipantBase = {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  extras: { [property: string]: string };
};

// Doesn't work.
function getAllowedEntry<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<T, AllowedPropertyTypes>>(participant: T, key: K): AllowedPropertyTypes {
  return participant[key];
}

// Works just fine.
function getAllowedParticipantEntry<K extends PropertiesOfType<ParticipantBase, AllowedPropertyTypes>>(participant: ParticipantBase, key: K): AllowedPropertyTypes {
  return participant[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should replace your return type from **AllowedPropertyTypes** to
>   **T[K]**

**Error Hint: Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'AllowedPropertyTypes'.**

```
function getAllowedEntry<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<T, AllowedPropertyTypes>>(participant: T, key: K): T[K] {
      return participant[key];
    }
```

Comment: If I do this, will I still be able to guarantee that `T[K]` is of type `AllowedPropertyTypes`?

Comment: Yes of course as you are guaranting that key passed to get getAllowedEntry function is of type AllowedPropertyTypes.